# Is there a way to use full functionality of Magic Trackpad with ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gnome, 17.10, ubuntu-gnome, multi-touch, magic-trackpad

What way would you recommend to take advantage of multi-touch gestures with MagicTrackpad2 on Ubuntu 17.10 (Gnome)?

Next aspects are of particular interest: possibility to configure 1 to 4 finger gestures that distinguish between direction, tap and click to be mapped to some keyboard key combination or mouse input.

Seemingly available options:

- gist
- touchegg (crashed on start installed from apt-get)
- xf86-input-multitouch - just mentioning, have no idea what that is.
- https://github.com/mpiannucci/gnome-shell-extended-gestures - some basic gestures for gnome
- [fusuma](https://github.com/iberianpig/fusuma)
- [libinput-gestures](https://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures)

Is there any success story around?

Comment: `libinput-debug-events` shows that MagicTrackpad2 is recognized only as a pointer device and does not produce any gesture event